# How can I select the most recent date from multiple columns in a pandas df?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with 5 columns. One column contains `Account` numbers and the other four have dates(`Billing`, `Billing1`, `Billing2`, `Billing3`). I need to create a new column containing the most recent date between those four columns.

How can I select the most recent date from four different columns?

```
dates_dict = {'Account':{0: '1', 1: '2', 2: '3', 3: '4', 4: '5'},'Billing':{0: np.nan, 1: Timestamp('2014-06-23 00:00:00'), 2: Timestamp('2014-06-23 00:00:00'), 3: Timestamp('2014-06-23 00:00:00'), 4:  np.nan}, 'Billing 1': {0:  np.nan, 1: Timestamp('2015-06-23 00:00:00'), 2: Timestamp('2014-06-23 00:00:00'), 3: Timestamp('2015-06-23 00:00:00'), 4:  np.nan}, 'Billing 2': {0:  np.nan, 1: Timestamp('2016-06-23 00:00:00'), 2: Timestamp('2015-06-23 00:00:00'), 3: Timestamp('2016-06-23 00:00:00'), 4:  np.nan}, 'Billing 3': {0:  np.nan, 1: Timestamp('2017-06-23 00:00:00'), 2: Timestamp('2016-06-23 00:00:00'), 3: Timestamp('2017-06-23 00:00:00'), 4:  np.nan}}
dates_df = pd.DataFrame(dates_dict)
```

Comment: Not able to create `dates_df`. `NameError: name 'Timestamp' is not defined`.

Comment: @MayankPorwal, try `from pandas import Timestamp`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply apply the max function column-wise over the subset of columns:

```
cols = [x for x in dates_df.columns if 'billing' in x.lower()]
dates_df['most_recent_date'] = dates_df[cols].max(axis=1)
```

Comment: change it to ```'billing'```

Answer (score 2):

Use [`df.filter`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.filter.html) with [`df.max`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.max.html):

```
In [1183]: cols = dates_df.filter(like='Billing').columns
In [1185]: dates_df['max_date'] = dates_df[cols].max(1)

In [1186]: dates_df
Out[1186]: 
  Account    Billing  Billing 1  Billing 2  Billing 3   max_date
0       1        NaT        NaT        NaT        NaT        NaT
1       2 2014-06-23 2015-06-23 2016-06-23 2017-06-23 2017-06-23
2       3 2014-06-23 2014-06-23 2015-06-23 2016-06-23 2016-06-23
3       4 2014-06-23 2015-06-23 2016-06-23 2017-06-23 2017-06-23
4       5        NaT        NaT        NaT        NaT        NaT
```